# How to set an AutoField ID to a nested model in django-nonrel?

Tags: django, mongodb, django-nonrel

I need an ID for a nested model in django-nonrel, for example for each comment from an entry.

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    comments = ListField(EmbeddedModelField('Comment'))

class Comment(models.Model):
    text =  CharField(max_length=200)
```

I tried:

```
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
id = models.NativeAutoField(primary_key=True) 
id = models.CharField(max_length=200, primary_key=True)
```

None seems to generate an Id automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something with `CharField(..., default=ObjectId)`?